# Gnome3 shows only wallpaper after login

Tags: gnome3

I had a debian squeeze, and decided I wanted more modern software versions. I set my repositories to testing and started to run all the updates. I further installed some software. No gnome extensions except for tweak-tool.

I definitely rebooted during this whole process. I have my debian on a usb hard drive, so I then took it on another computer and when I logged in the desktop showed only the wallpaper. The black bar on the top disappeared upon clicking "login" and about a second later the black mousepointer turned white. Next nothing. I see the debian wallpaper (the login screen one), not the one I had set up in gnome, and nothing else. No panels, not app switcher, no right click, nothing. I can go to tty with cntr-alt-Fx.

Now I brought it back to the machine where I had it working before, but that has the same problem now.

I looked around in the logs and on the web, but found nothing much special. Tried restarting gdm, tried reconfiguring gdm and xorg with dpkg. No avail.

**Im pretty stuck with an unusable system...**

any hints appreciated. It seems some other people have asked about similar issues, but the answers don't work for me...

ps: is there a way to turn on fallback from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I had uninstalled the gnome-session package, probably by uninstalling evolution. After reinstalling that it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the samething: after login only shows the wallpaper, but no tool bar or anything". But in my case, the new monitor I was using had some cables I didn't know why where there and I pluged everything, so computer showed the desktop as a second desktop. To fix it, just needed to press 'super' and type 'screen' (you wont see what you are typing). Then it appears a window where you can mirror the 'two' monitors and fix the problem without take cables out.